# Getting white screen on blackberry simulator while running blackberry with sencha Touch2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, blackberry-webworks

I'm developing a blackberry webworks application using sencha touch . And after making build getting white screen only.

here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-
    width,user-scalable=no" />
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="www/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="www/sencha-touch.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 new Ext.Application({ 
launch: function() { 
    new Ext.Panel({ 
        fullscreen: true, 
        dockedItems: [{xtype:'toolbar', title:'My First App'}], 
        layout: 'fit', 
        styleHtmlContent: true, 
        html: '<h2>Hello World!</h2>I did it!' 
     }); 
 } 
  </script>
  </head>
 <body>
 <p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone done this? Please help me.

Comment: Other way i also tried is:  I created a sencha application its working fine as a sencha project. i package it using command(sencha app build package). after that i put all the package file in the www folder of blackberry webworks application. and when i run this using ripple emulator i got white screen only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include one of them :) sencha-touch-all.js is a debug version of sencha-touch.js

and second looks like you have missed include css file.

Cheers, Oleg